# LINQ - c# flatten collection to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data structure:

```
class customer
{
      List<string> photoIds;
      string fullname;
}
```

Sample collection:

new customer() { new [] {"1", "2", "3"}, "Cust 1"};

new customer() { new [] {"5", "8", "10"}, "Cust 2"};

new customer() { new [] {"3", "11", "4"}, "Cust 3"};

what i'm trying to achieve is converting the below data to Dictionary, where key is the photoid and value is fullname

```
{1, Cust 1}
{2, Cust 1}
{3, Cust 1}
{5, Cust 2}
{8, Cust 2}
{10, Cust 2}
{3, Cust 3}
{11, Cust 3}
{4, Cust 3}
```

any helps?

Comment: @Grant..  it's just pseudo code..   just giving ppl idea of what i'm trying to achieve..   why do you need to have a compile code for?

Comment: @bet - Did you get a chance to check my answer..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) and [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.100).aspx) Enumerable methods:-

```
var result = customers.SelectMany(x => x.photoIds, (custObj, photoIds) => 
                                                         new { 
                                                                 custObj, photoIds 
                                                             })
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.photoIds, x => x.custObj.fullname);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AHBwpd).